# What is the difference between the following two code snippets?

Tags: c++, recursion, depth-first-search

DFS 1:

```
bool dfs(int source, int color, int dist) {
    vis[source] = true;
    if (source == dist)
        return true;
    for (auto x : adj[source]) {

        int new_node = x.first;
        if (!vis[new_node]) {
            int new_color = x.second;
            if (new_color == color)
                return dfs(new_node, new_color, dist);
                   
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

DFS 2:

```
bool dfs(int source, int color, int dist) {
    vis[source] = true;
    if (source == dist)
        return true;
    for (auto x : adj[source]) {

        int new_node = x.first;
        if (!vis[new_node]) {
            int new_color = x.second;
            if (new_color == color)
                if (dfs(new_node, new_color, dist))
                       return true;
                   
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

The line that confuses me

`return dfs(new_node, new_color, dist);`

and

```
if (dfs(new_node, new_color, dist))
        return true;
```

What this code is doing check if there's a path between nodes `source` and `dist` such that all the edges of the path have the same color. The second one works fine, but the first one doesn't work. Is there a difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version with `return dfs(new_node, new_color, dist);` will *always* return from the function after that call, whether that returned value is `true` or `false`.

However, the `if (dfs(new_node, new_color, dist)) return true;` will make the recursive call but *only exit the `for` loop* (by returning) if that call returns `true`. If it returns `false`, the `for` loop continues to its next iteration.